# How to fix SlickNav not initliazing

Tags: javascript, css, slicknav

I have a website where I installed SlickNav. I have it calling properly, and the linking works properly, however it doesn't seem to want to initialize in the site itself. I'm calling it via the following:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/mta360/dist/styles/slicknav.css" />
  <script src="/wp-content/themes/mta360/dist/scripts/slicknav.js"></script>
```

The menu code is as follows:

```
<header>
<!-- Header Start -->
<div class="header-area">
    <div class="main-header ">
        <div class="header-top top-bg d-none d-lg-block">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        <div class="header-info-left">
                            <ul>
                                <li>1234567890</li>
                                <li>mta360seo@gmail.com</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="header-info-right">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Mon - Fri: 9:00 - 5:00</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="header-bottom  header-sticky">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <!-- Logo -->
                    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-1 col-md-1">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="index.html"><img src="/logo.png" alt=""></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                        <!-- Main-menu -->
                        <div class="main-menu f-right d-none d-lg-block">
                            <nav>
                                <ul id="navigation">
                                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Heating</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Cooling</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Press</a>
                                        <ul class="submenu">
                                            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Releases</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Company</a>
                                        <ul class="submenu">
                                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-3">
                        <!-- Header-btn -->
                        <div class="header-btn d-none d-lg-block">
                            <a href="#" class="get-btn">Quote</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Mobile Menu -->
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="mobile_menu d-block d-lg-none"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Header End -->
```

Is there something I'm missing? It works for my local testing, but when I compile and try to use it on the actual site, it just doesn't want to initialize at all. Is there something I'm missing?

It's a wordpress site using Sage 9, in case that helps with the diagnosis.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize it using Javascript code.

The 2 first libraries you are calling are the CSS slicknav library and the JS slicknav library. You also need to load jQuery for slicknav to work.

So add this to your code at the beginning:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#menu').slicknav({

// Label for menu button. 
// Use an empty string for no label.
'label' : 'MENU', 

// If true, the mobile menu is a copy of the original.
'duplicate': true, 

// The duration of the sliding animation.
'duration': true, 

// other parameters see here: https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Creating-A-Responsive-Mobile-Navigation-Menu-with-slicknav-jQuery-Plugin.html //

});

});
```

also you need to specify an ID "menu" to the `<ul>` element like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Finally, make sure your HTML markup follows the specified structure for slick nav which is:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li>Home
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li>Plugins
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Latest</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Most Popular</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Recommended</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Publishing</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Top <a href="#">Menu</a> 2</a></li>
<li>Top Menu 3</li>
<li>Top Menu 4
<ul>
<li><a href="#">item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

more here: https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Creating-A-Responsive-Mobile-Navigation-Menu-with-slicknav-jQuery-Plugin.html

Comment: It's using JQuery in the site. And I have an ID assigned to the menu. This is the URL of the site I'm trying to get it to work on: http://allensworthheatingandcooling.digitalpreviewsite.com/

Comment: OK thanks for sharing the live preview link. So what exactly is the issue on the page again?

Comment: Slicknav won't initialize. When you resize the browser, it should show the mobile menu, but it doesn't. That's what I'm struggling with. When I check dev tools, it's like calling the slicknav whatsoever despite it being in the head and footer

Comment: @M.Straw are you open to using a much more simple approach to responsive menus?

Comment: 100% I am. I just was using slicknav because it's what I've had. If I can recreate my navbars and menus with something simplier that'll work with a wordpress site, I'm all for it

Comment: are you still needing help? i'm avai.

Comment: Yes I do. Just can't seem to figure out a simple/easy way to achieve what I need.

Comment: Do you have an online example of what you want on anotehr site?

Comment: unfortunately no. I had been using SlickNav for some builds. But it just doesn't seem to want to work right with my wordpress sites